# How can i check Stage Channel topic?(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to check the topic of the stage for a command. Something like this:

```py
await message.delete()

stage = discord.Object(id='828995257135267950')
channeltopic = discord.StageChannel.topic(id=stage)
embed=discord.Embed(title="Stage Topic", description="This embed can show the current topic of the Stage", color=0xff2b2b)
embed.set_author(name="Administrator command")
embed.add_field(name="Current topic", value=channeltopic)
embed.set_footer(text="DiscordBot 2021")

await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs out for that? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=stage#discord.CategoryChannel.stage_channels

Comment: Yes but i can't understand it

Answer (score 0):

Stage channels do have a topic. The topic can be get via [`discord.StageChannel.topic`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=stage#discord.StageChannel.topic)

---

Guessing that `828995257135267950` is your stage-channel-id:

```
stage = message.guild.get_channel(828995257135267950)
channeltopic = stage.topic
```